# How to see joins (one-to-many) in the QGIS 2.18.14?

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I made a join with two tables - one to many.

**territories** and **roads**. Meaning, one **territory** have many **roads**.

**territories** -> 98 territories/features
**roads** -> 529 roads/features

So, in the **territories**, properties, made a join:

[image]

But in the attribute table I still see only 98 territories. Shouldn't see more than 98? Shouldn't see another rows for the related roads...?

[image]

Comment: I want to add information on how I solved this. Where are my mistakes and the solution I found with "relations".